# Displaying Date from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I know this is covered a lot in SO, but i can't find the exact solution i need so please bear with me.
When users submit an entry to my database, i'm storing the date and time in a DATETIME field called date.

Now when i come to echo the date their particular entry was posted, i'm using:

```
<p>Posted:<br /><?php echo $rsjobinfo['date'];?></p>
```

Of course this is displaying the full date and time and i only want to display something like 7 July, 2011.

So above my echo statement i've done this:

```
$date = $rsjobinfo['date'];
$date = date('j F, Y');
```

Which, if i echo $date, displays today's date in the correct format, but i cannot figure out how to apply that format to the date that's being pulled from the database. If i replace

```
  <p>Posted:<br /><?php echo $rsjobinfo['date'];?></p>
```

with

```
  <p>Posted:<br /><?php echo $date;?></p>
```

It just echo's todays date (albeit in the format i want), rather than the database date.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass the right date to `date()`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
$date = date('j F, Y', strtotime($rsjobinfo['date']));
```

Comment: OP should also read up about strtotime as well, thats an important part of this correct answer!

Comment: @Jack Murcdoch thanks Jack, i can't mark this question answered for another 10 minutes apparantly but yours and Radu's answers are spot on.

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = date('j F, Y', strtotime($rsjobinfo['date']));
```

See the following documentation for more details:

- [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime)
- [`date()`](http://php.net/date)

Comment: Magic, that has worked a treat. I did have a strtotime in the date variable but not matching it to $rsjobinfo. Thanks so much. Dan

Answer (score 2):

As other suggested, you should use PHP functions like `strtotime()` and `date()`:

```
$date = $rsjobinfo['date'] ;
$dateToPrint = date('j F, Y', strtotime($date) ) ;
echo $dateToPrint ;
```

You could also use MySQL [**`DATE_FORMAT()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
$sql = "SELECT ...
             , `date`
             , DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%e %M, %Y') AS dateToPrint 
        FROM 
            ...
       " ;

$dateToPrint = $rsjobinfo['dateToPrint'] ;
echo $dateToPrint ;
```